# Unexpected seemingly random errors in Android studio

Tags: android, exception, crash

I was working on a project in Android Studio and was regularly compiling the code running it on my device to make sure everything was in working order. Suddenly the main activity crashes, several times after compiling several separate times. I checked the logcat and the error was reported as being due to failure to recognize the layout. I didn't understand why, as I hadn't changed any of the code in the main activity.

In fact the only thing that had changed over the course of those few days was that I had added a bunch of new layouts into the large, xlarge and landscape layout folders. I deleted the `setContentView(R.layout.main_screen)` and rewrote it verbatim and the code worked. I proceeded to the second activity and again a crash, this time due to a null pointer exception; again I had made no changes. I tried copying the code, deleted the Activity, created a new one with the same name, and pasted the code. Suddenly it worked fine. This happened in almost EVERY activity, crashes and errors for seemingly random reasons all of which were fixed by simply copying the code and pasting it verbatim.

Has anyone run into something similar or does anyone have any idea why something like this may have happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that various libraries I had imported were not being properly pulled across various machines: I would pull from github and the various support libraries and associated maven files were not being correctly pulled. Studio's built in handling of various xml files if auto-completion is used corrected the problem by deleting and then retyping a particular line of code.